# How to DSolve this differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations, special-functions

How can I find `h[r]` from this equation?
I need `h[r]` or its `r` derivative.

```
(E^(Derivative[1][h][r]^2/(2*b^2))*Sqrt[r^4*Sin[\[Theta][]]^2]*
(-(r*Derivative[1][h][r]^2*Derivative[2][h][r]) - 
b^2*(2*Derivative[1][h][r] + r*Derivative[2][h][r])))/
(4*b^2*Pi*r) == 0
```

In fact, the output of `Mma`is kind of vague. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: What's `\[Theta][]`?

Comment: @xzczd Another coordinate (non-related to the `r` coordinate)

Comment: I mean, why is there a `[]`?

Comment: @xzczd it is not important, you can remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = (E^(h'[r]^2/(2*b^2))*
      Sqrt[r^4*Sin[θ]^2]*(-(r*h'[r]^2*h''[r]) - 
        b^2*(2*h'[r] + r*h''[r])))/(4*b^2*Pi*r) == 0;

DSolve[eqn, h, r]
```

[image]

Verifying the solution,

```
eqn /. sol // Simplify

(* {True, True} *)
```

Since `h[r]` is an integral, it is easier to deal with its derivative

```
h'[x] /. sol

(* {-b Sqrt[ProductLog[E^((2 C[1])/b^2)/(b^2 x^4)]], 
 b Sqrt[ProductLog[E^((2 C[1])/b^2)/(b^2 x^4)]]} *)
```

Plotting the derivative,

```
Plot[Evaluate@
  Table[
   Tooltip[h'[x] /. sol /. C[1] -> 1, b],
   {b, 1/2, 3/2, 1/2}],
 {x, -5, 5},
 PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Automatic},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank U for your answer. The thing is, for large values of the `b`, one should have the standard form (for derivative answer) as $\alpha/r^2$ where $\alpha$ is a constant. How can I find the integration constant (related to $\alpha$)?

Comment: I don't understand why you think I would know anything about your problem beyond what you stated in your question.